# How redirect mysite.com/123-category?orderby=name&orderway=asc to mysite.com/123-category

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In my website is category page for example mysite.com/123-category. When the user sorts the products, url is mysite.com/123-category?orderby=name&orderway=asc. 
I need to rewrite this link something like this mysite.com/123-category.

In htaccess file I have the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /1451/category.php?id_category=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use htaccess file to strip off query parameters. Just use preg_replace function and strip it off

Comment: I still have a problem. I use prestashop system and I do not know which file can I edit.